Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8,9' apply: false] was not found in any of rhe following sources
Я только создал новый проект в android studio, ничего не успел написать, как при сборке приложения возникла такая ошибка. Прогу переустонавливал раза 3. Несколько раз создавал новый проект. Обновлял grade. SDK указал. В settings, вроде, всё верно. Ничего не помогло.
Что делать?
Снизу фотки build.gradle.kts и settings.gradle.kts.



Этот вопрос похож на: Ошибка Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

Те ответы мне не помогают. Тем более, вопрос написан 1 год и 7 месяцев назад. За это время программа обновилась. Может, есть другие решения?

Программы то обновляются, но проблема с доступом к интернет ресурсу от этого не меняется. Приведите хотя бы stack trace из Gradle, пальцем в небо тыкать чтобы угадать причину никто не будет.
